# Why isn't rotatef swapping the values?

Tags: common-lisp

I'm trying to go through the all the possible combinations of n values in a m length array. Using nil to represent empty places. In this example n is 2 and m is 3

```
;; ('a 'b nil) -> ('a nil 'b)
;; (nil 'a 'b) -> signal end of the rep.
;; ('a 'b nil) -> ('a nil 'b) -> (nil 'a 'b) -> Run out of possiblites.
;;
;; ('a 'b nil nil)
(defun next-candidate (candidate)
  (labels ((iter-helper (xs &optional prev-item)
             (if (and (listp xs)
                      (null  (first xs)))
                 (progn
                   (rotatef (first xs) prev-item)
                   candidate)
                 (iter-helper (rest xs) (first xs)))))
    (when (null (first candidate))
      (signal 'no-more-combinations))
    (iter-helper candidate)))


(let ((test (list 1 nil 3)))
  (next-candidate test))
=> (1 1 3) Expected (nil 1 3)
```

Why is rotaref not swapping the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get `(1 1 3)` as Rainer does, the reason being that when `(rotatef (first xs) prev-item)` is invoked `xs` is `(nil 3)` and `prev-item` is `1`. After that call, `xs` is `(1 3)`, and - because `xs` is the `cdr` of `candidate` - that means `candidate`, the return value, is `(1 1 3)`.

To give you an idea of how `rotatef` works, this is how you could produce your expected result in a simple case:

```
(let ((test (list 1 nil 3)))
  (rotatef (first test) (second test))
  test)
```

`rotatef` is destructive, meaning when you change something that shares structure with something else (as with `xs` and `candidate`) you will see the change in both places.

Here's something that I think is closer to what you're looking for, though I'm not completely sure.

```
(defun next-candidate (candidate)
  (labels ((next (xs)
             (if (null (first xs))
                 (signal 'no-more-combinations)
                 (progn
                   (rotatef (first xs)
                            (second xs)
                            (third xs))
                   xs))))
    (next candidate)))
```

Comment: I am aware of the concept of structural sharing. I was under the impression that the place of (first xs) being passed between function calls. If that is the case I think vectors will be more appropriate than lists. Thank you!

Comment: Whether a list or vector would be more appropriate probably depends on the larger context. You could stick with a list but avoid modifying the one that's passed in either by first copying it (with copy-list) and then destructively modifying that copy, or by building up a new list from scratch.

Comment: Regarding rotatef, a "place" is basically anywhere that can hold a reference to an object, including the cells of a cons.

Comment: I forgot to add why I thought using vectors would be a solution. Going to pass around the indexes instead of the places and use nth to get the place.

Answer (score 3):

I see as output: `(1 1 3)`.

If you expect `(nil 1 3)`, then you should try to find out how it should set the first element of the list to `NIL`. Setting a local variable `prev-item` in a function via `ROTATEF` does not change the list at all.

Comment: Yeah, I miscopied the result from another attempt at writing  the function.